# Alamofire when data response Swift 4 Timer

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, asynchronous, alamofire

I have an Alamofire function like when data comes to insert data into Global NsDictionary

```
Common.Customers
```

Function is

```
static func PostAlomofire(format : RequestFormat)  {

    let loginParam: [String: Any] = [
        "searchTerm": format.Name,
        "pageSize": format.PageSize,
        "pageNumber": format.PageNumber ,
        "deviceId": format.DeviceId
    ]
print(loginParam)

  Alamofire.request("http://111.3.4.2/website/api/Customer/Search", method: .post, parameters: loginParam, encoding: JSONEncoding.prettyPrinted)
        .responseJSON { response in    
            let result = response.result
            print(result.value)
            if let dict = result.value as? Dictionary<String,AnyObject>
            {
                if let innerDic = dict["results"]
                {

                    Common.Customers = innerDic as! [NSDictionary]
                }
            }
            print(Common.Customers)
    }

}
```

This code is working. But, if I didn't use the timer `Common.Customers` always nill.
When ı want to call this function, I am calling like

```
  WebService.PostAlomofire(format: format)
    _ = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.5, repeats: false) { timer in
        self.Table_tv.reloadData()

    }
```

but if data were not coming 0.5 seconds, this code doesn't work.

```
Timer.scheduledTimer
```

Is correct way or not?
It doesn't feel safe to me. What can I use if it is not true?

Comment: It's **not** the correct way. You have to use a completion handler or call `reloadData` instead of `print(Common.Customers)`. And don't use `NSDictionary` in Swift.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a completion handler as this is not the job of a timer

```
static func PostAlomofire(format : RequestFormat,completion:@escaping(()-> Void)) {
       let loginParam: [String: Any] = [
    "searchTerm": format.Name,
    "pageSize": format.PageSize,
    "pageNumber": format.PageNumber ,
    "deviceId": format.DeviceId
]
print(loginParam)

 Alamofire.request("http://111.3.4.2/website/api/Customer/Search", method: .post, parameters: loginParam, encoding: JSONEncoding.prettyPrinted)
    .responseJSON { response in    
        let result = response.result
        print(result.value)
        if let dict = result.value as? [String: Any]
        {
            if let innerDic = dict["results"]
            {

                Common.Customers = innerDic as! [[String: Any]]
                completion()
            }
        }
        print(Common.Customers)
}
}
```

//

```
WebService.PostAlomofire(format: format) {
     self.Table_tv.reloadData()
}
```